# Powershell is ignoring expression after function call

Tags: powershell, syntax, expression

Here is a powershell script:

```
function PickANumber()
{
  12
}

function GetTheAnswer()
{
  PickANumber + 30
}

$answer = GetTheAnswer
write-output "The answer is $answer"
```

The output of this script is:

```
The answer is 12
```

As far as I call guess, this happens because powershell function calls do not have brackets around the arguments or commas between them, so `PickANumber + 30` is parsed as something like `PickANumber('+', 1)` instead of `PickANumber() + 1`. And this is not an error, the unused args are simply ignored (like with JavaScript).

If you change it slightly, then the answer is 42:

```
function GetTheAnswer()
{
  $a = PickANumber
  $a + 30
}
```

But surely there is a way of doing this on one line?

I'm posting here because this is going to bite someone else too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid this pitfall you could define your functions like this

```
function PickANumber()
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param()

  12
}
```

When executing `PickANumber + 30` you will get the error

> PickANumber : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument '+'.

Comment: Great, this causes the incorrect code to give an error. Now combine with the other answer "(PickANumber) +  30" for fixing the error given.

Answer (score 8):

The correct call is

```
(PickANumber) + 30
```

The original code `PickANumber + 30` means a call to `PickANumber` with two
arguments `+` and `30` which are simply ignored by `PickANumber`.